# How to proxy all traffic received by Windows using Linux and redsocks?

Tags: linux, proxy, iptables, nat

I have a Windows machine where all of it's traffic is routed through a Linux machine simply by doing changing the Windows route :
`route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.48` where `192.168.1.48` is the ip address of the Linux machine. The thing is, I want the traffic pass by a socks5 proxy, I already know how to do that using `redsocks` but the problem is that I don't know how to setup correctly `iptables` so all work correctly. I want that the traffic coming from Windows is "proxied" to the socks5 server but also the traffic coming from Linux itself. With these rules added onto iptables. the traffic coming from Linux "proxied" as expected and everything works fine, but I loose the connection on the windows side. IP forwarding is enabled on Linux side.

What I have tried, is simply to add these rule :

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

sudo iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 12345
    
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDSOCKS
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDSOCKS
    
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDSOCKS
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDSOCKS
```

the redsocks daemon listen to the port 12345